# Is it possible to use jQuery in a greasemonkey script without breaking a browser extension working on the same site?

Tags: javascript, jquery, greasemonkey, userscripts, tampermonkey

I have written a small script in tampermonkey (chrome version of greasemonkey), which uses jQuery. I also have a browser extension installed which is supposed to work on the same site as my script does. All was well while I was only working with simple javascript, but as soon as I put "@require      http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js" at the start of my script, the extension stopped working. If I disable the script, the extension starts working again. Is there any way to circumvent this issue?

Comment: Check if jQ is already loaded and use the existing version if so?

Comment: There is not enough detail here to provide a meaningful answer. Can you at least share the exact error being output?

Comment: Please, share the userscript your wrote.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try this:

```
this.$ = this.jQuery = jQuery.noConflict(true);
```